# Fabric sudo as another user with root privileges

Tags: bash, fabric

I am writing a Fabric deploy script that gets run as user `MyAppUser` (host "MyAppUser@myapp.mycompany.com", ssh keys working, so no password required).  One of the steps involves copying a file into `/etc/init` and changing the permissions so in future deploys `MyAppUser` can overwrite that file.

`MyAppUser` is not a sudoer.  Nor should it be.  In order to execute a copy into `/etc/init` I need elevated privileges...so I'm stuck prompting the user for a username and executing:

```
run('su %s -c "sudo cp /home/myappuser/git/myapp/myapp.conf /etc/init"')
```

Which works, but prompts me for the same password twice. (I *am* a sudoer).

Many questions here, but the central few are:

1. Why doesn't `sudo("sudo cp /home/myappuser/git/myapp/myapp.conf /etc/init", user='Me)` work as expected?  It looks like the first sudo (run by fabric) is ignoring `user`.
2. Is there a better way to execute a command requiring root permissions as another user who is a sudoer? (A Bash question, not a fabric question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You said MyAppUser wasn't in sudoers. So it can't run sudo. Use the debug flag to see this, but you're essentially doing this:

```
$ ssh MyAppUser@myapp.mycompany.com "sudo -u me 'sudo cp ...'"
```

So if MyAppUser can't sudo at all, then fabric connecting as this use can not sudo.

2: If you have multiple users able to connect to this machine, use the settings() context manager or the execute() function and supply me (see prompted user) as the user to connect with in the host string. eg:

```
execute(setup_task, host="me@myapp.mycompany.com")
```

Where setup_task is the task doing the copy into the init dir.

Comment: This solves the problem I outlined above.  What i eventually did was decide that when setting up my remote servers I'd make it a prereq that they own the file they'd be writing to, then I'd use `>` to write to it.